# data.table R ; how to preserve list element name by fwrite?

Tags: r, list, data.table, fwrite

I have a following list of data.tables;

```
l[1:2]
$cluster1
           rn        p_val avg_log2FC pct.1 pct.2    p_val_adj
       <char>        <num>      <num> <num> <num>        <num>
  1: Adamts20 1.438101e-65   1.030705 0.001 0.118 4.314302e-62
  2:      Gal 3.233897e-54  16.358484 0.006 0.208 9.701690e-51
  3:     Hrnr 1.295286e-51  14.374645 0.007 0.182 3.885858e-48
  4:      Ngb 4.143060e-44   1.925631 0.021 0.240 1.242918e-40
  5:    Svep1 3.872262e-41   8.232291 0.283 0.582 1.161679e-37
 ---                                                          
366:   Cyfip2 1.468792e-05   2.417948 0.056 0.118 4.406375e-02
367:   Fcgr2b 1.505992e-05  -4.719973 0.231 0.148 4.517976e-02
368:      Ogn 1.538930e-05   9.708295 0.242 0.339 4.616791e-02
369:   Lrrc15 1.549036e-05  -2.966498 0.241 0.352 4.647109e-02
370: AY036118 1.624054e-05   2.602963 0.715 0.788 4.872162e-02

$cluster2
                rn         p_val avg_log2FC pct.1 pct.2     p_val_adj
            <char>         <num>      <num> <num> <num>         <num>
  1:        Samd13 1.841651e-127  8.7785032 0.001 0.144 5.524952e-124
  2:         Gata1  2.210414e-99 17.0522687 0.002 0.126  6.631242e-96
  3:        Col4a4  1.250827e-58  9.6145811 0.583 0.254  3.752481e-55
  4:           Bsx  4.028430e-54 18.2214242 0.202 0.568  1.208529e-50
  5:        Gimap3  4.650536e-53 -1.6106639 0.017 0.255  1.395161e-49
 ---                                                                 
217:          Cd3e  1.452524e-05 18.6983055 0.131 0.175  4.357573e-02
218:       Selenom  1.455810e-05  0.9648215 0.293 0.201  4.367429e-02
219: A330069E16Rik  1.469167e-05 -5.4387846 0.388 0.282  4.407501e-02
220:         Lypd1  1.560834e-05 -2.1249661 0.176 0.100  4.682501e-02
221:          Alad  1.633998e-05 -1.1929284 0.226 0.175  4.901995e-02
```

I'd like to export this list to a csv file by fwrite.  I run this following code;

```
lapply(l[1:2], function(x) fwrite(as.data.table(x), "DGE.csv"))
```

A resulting csv file doesn't have list element names,  $cluster1 and $cluster.  Are there any ways to add list element names as the header of each of the element list and column headers as a follow desired output by using fwrite ?;

```
cluster1
   rn   p_val   avg_log2FC  pct.1   pct.2   p_val_adj
Samd13  1.84E-127   8.778503219 0.001   0.144   5.52E-124
Gata1   2.21E-99    17.05226868 0.002   0.126   6.63E-96
Col4a4  1.25E-58    9.614581115 0.583   0.254   3.75E-55
Bsx     4.03E-54    18.22142419 0.202   0.568   1.21E-50
Gimap3  4.65E-53    -1.61066387 0.017   0.255   1.40E-49
Gm26825 9.54E-51    12.96067221 0.341   0.596   2.86E-47
Erfe    3.72E-48    11.74946067 0.007   0.156   1.12E-44




cluster2
    rn  p_val   avg_log2FC  pct.1   pct.2   p_val_adj
Samd13  1.63E-12    15.05539372 0.038   0.141   4.90E-09
Frmd5   1.75E-12    -1.28277874 0.154   0.318   5.26E-09
Pla2g2f 2.06E-12    -1.51234633 0.142   0.056   6.17E-09
Aldh1a2 2.25E-12    5.127605606 0.274   0.426   6.75E-09
Fxyd2   2.51E-12    5.246386986 0.626   0.805   7.53E-09
Adam30  3.15E-12    1.53746735  0.203   0.362   9.44E-09
Gpr35   3.15E-12    -3.18282304 0.691   0.516   9.46E-09
Il10rb  3.65E-12    1.473277609 0.42    0.598   1.10E-08
Gk5     3.72E-12    -14.0221264 0.177   0.074   1.12E-08
    .......
```

Comment: why would you want that? It will create a file that will be difficult to deal with. Also note that you are overwriting the file. Hence only the last datatable will be written to the csv file. The best option is to write different csv files with the cluster names. ie `cluster1.csv` `cluster2.csv` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to writing separate files: append the list-name as a column, then `rbindlist` them, write them, and when you read them then `split` on that column name.

Sample data:

```r
library(data.table)
ZZ <- lapply(list(mt1=mtcars[1:3,], mt2=mtcars[4:6,]), as.data.table)
ZZ
# $mt1
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
# 2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
# 3:  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
# $mt2
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:  21.4     6   258   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
# 2:  18.7     8   360   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
# 3:  18.1     6   225   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
```

Append, combine, write:

```r
fwrite(rbindlist(ZZ, idcol = "name"), "~/Downloads/ZZ.csv")
```

The resulting file, that can be read by any vanilla CSV reader:

```r
name,mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb
mt1,21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
mt1,21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
mt1,22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
mt2,21.4,6,258,110,3.08,3.215,19.44,1,0,3,1
mt2,18.7,8,360,175,3.15,3.44,17.02,0,0,3,2
mt2,18.1,6,225,105,2.76,3.46,20.22,1,0,3,1
```

Reading it in and restoring the original object format:

```r
ZZ2 <- fread("ZZ.csv")
ZZ2 <- lapply(split(ZZ2, ZZ2$name), function(x) x[, name := NULL])
ZZ2
# $mt1
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <int> <int> <int> <num> <num> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
# 2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
# 3:  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
# $mt2
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <int> <int> <int> <num> <num> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:  21.4     6   258   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
# 2:  18.7     8   360   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
# 3:  18.1     6   225   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
```